# How to find unknown operator A for two known vectors in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, linear-algebra, solver

Say I have a matrix `A` that has four symbolic values `a, b, c, d` and the rest are zero. The positions of the values are known:

```matlab
sym a b c d
A = [a b 0 0; c 0 0 0; 0 d 0 0; 0 0 0 0]
```

(Note, I randomly placed these symbols. The dimensions I'm dealing with are bigger than this.)

Now say I have two vectors `x` and `y` that are known exactly. I want to find the values for `a, b, c, d` that take x to y. Specifically, I want to solve for all/any `A`'s in the equation `A*x = y` in MATLAB. How is this done?

Comment: I hope `y(4)==0`, otherwise your equation is incorrect. Also, only the first two values of `x` are relevant in your equation, the other two can be ignored.

Comment: @CrisLuengo These are just sample values...in my case, I know there are solutions. I need to find a way to get a list of these solutions in MATLAB. Do you know?

Comment: All I'm saying is that you should make sure that the example you give is relevant to your actual problem. Do give the `x` and `y` too, to provide a complete problem for someone to solve. It makes it a lot easier to provide an answer if the question is complete.

Comment: This is simply an over-determined linear system. See here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve-a-system-of-linear-equations.html. If you want to use the symbolic package -- the easy route, you can generate the code for inputs of `solve` and then use `solve`. If efficiency matters -- ie. size is large, try to split A into its factors and solve numerically.

Comment: A curious problem. Mostly unrelated to programming. I can only provide an answer re functions in Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create the equation with `A*x.' == y.'` and solve this equation.

```
%random (but determined) system of equation
syms a b c d
A   = [c b 0 0; 
       a 0 0 0;
       0 d 0 0; 
       0 0 c 0] 

x   = [1 2 3 4]
y   = [1 2 3 4]

%create the equation
eqn = A*x.' == y.'

%solve the equation
res = solve(eqn)
```

But I don't understand why you've not created a **coefficient** matrix:

```
A = [0 2 1 0; % x is now useless because all the coefficient are contained in this matrix
     1 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 2;
     0 0 3 0]
```

So now you can solve the system easily with:

```
A\y.'
```

Which is IMO the matlab way to solve a determined system of linear equation.

Noticed that you can use `A = double(equationsToMatrix(A*x.'))` to transform your **symbolic matrix** `A` into a **coefficient matrix** `A`.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Use the symbolic [`solve`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve-a-system-of-linear-equations.html).

You need to generate the inputs for `solve` in the appropriate syntax. You can actually make a "symbolic equation" using `expr1 == expr2` where `expr1, expr2` are symbolic objects.

For example,

```
B=A*x;

eqn1 = B(1)==y(1);
```

Conveniently, you can produce a symbolic array by the like of `B==y`. So you don't have to enumerate the elements of `B`.

**Solution 2**

Express your problem in the proper form of linear system first. That is, express `A*x` as `X*[a;b;c;d]` where elements of `X` are one of the elements of `x`.

The position of a, b, c, d, ..., etc gives you the basis matrices that add to A. For example, if you start with

```
A = sparse(4);
A(2,1) = c;
```

It simply means the 2nd element of `A*x` is a sum containing `x(1)*c`. Since `c` is the 3rd element of `[a;b;c;d]`,

```
X(2,3) = x(1);
```

Since you start with positions of a, b, c, d, ..., etc, you should be able to assign the elements of `X` directly.

You can then use the usual algorithms to find the inverse of `X` efficiently, including [`lu`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lu.html). If you want convenience, `inv(X)` should work.

---

Note, depending the size of `A` and the number of unknowns, your system can be under- or over-determined, a solution may or may not exist. You need to handle that separately in either solution.

Also note, for the math problem of expressing `A*x` as `X*[a;b;c;d]`, the above hint is sufficient for a question in SO. You should see to a proof yourself.

Note again, if you want efficiency, avoid using symbolic objects wherever not required. (Unless you need to do symbolic integrals, symbolic objects are not required.)